# Getting Liquibase SQL Server error 'Cannot find the object ... because it doesn't exist or you do not have permissions'

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

I have a demo SQL Server database running in a Docker container and I'm testing out Liquibase on it. I created a changelog file and put in two changesets that would remove two columns from a particular table.

This is my Liquibase changelog file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.6.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-4.6.xsd ">

    <changeSet id="1" author="mdailey">
        <dropColumn tableName="Sales.Invoices" columnName="RunPosition">
        </dropColumn>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="2" author="mdailey">
        <dropColumn tableName="Sales.Invoices" columnName="DeliveryRun">
        </dropColumn>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

When I run `liquibase update` I keep getting the following error:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Cannot find the object "Sales.Invoices" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions. [Failed SQL: (4902) ALTER TABLE [Sales.Invoices] DROP COLUMN RunPosition]
```

I'm using the [sample database WideWorldImporters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/wide-world-importers-what-is?view=sql-server-ver15) Microsoft provides. The schema is Sales so the table name is correct. I have a user and login named sqladmin and the login info is in the Liquibase properties file. Here's the properties file:

```
# Enter the path for your changelog file.
changeLogFile=changelog/db.changelog-root.xml

# Enter the Target database 'url' information #
liquibase.command.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1401;database=WideWorldImporters

# Enter the username for your Target database.
liquibase.command.username: sqladmin    

# Enter the password for your Target database.
liquibase.command.password: <StrongPassword>
```

I added sqladmin to the db_datawriter role so it has enough permissions. When I run a T-SQL statement in SQL Server as 'sqladmin' to drop the same column from the same table it executes successfully. I think the problem is with Liquibase but I can't figure what.

Comment: I believe there is a separate attribute for schema name

Comment: I didn't want to set the schema name in the properties file because the database has multiple schemas. Are you saying I need to pass the schema name when doing the `liquibase update` command?

Comment: I passed the schema name but still got the same error ` liquibase --liquibaseSchemaName=Sales update`

Comment: [liquibase doc](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/drop-column.html#:~:text=To%20drop%20a%20single%20column,columnName%20attribute%20will%20be%20ignored.) has a schema name attribute that is separate from table name. I'm no expert here but you could try using a login that has a default schema name set to Sales and try your original approach. But the SQL statement in the error clearly indicates the problem - `TABLE [Sales.Invoices]` is very different from `TABLE [Sales].[Invoices]`

Comment: @SMor adding `schemaName="Sales"` to the changeset got it to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @SMor suggestion I figured out the solution.

In the changeset you don't add the schema name in front of the table, instead it needs to be added as a separate attribute.

```
<changeSet id="1" author="mdailey">
        <dropColumn schemaName="Sales" tableName="Invoices" columnName="RunPosition">
        </dropColumn>
    </changeSet>
```